# Closing Popup on tap over it in wp8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, popup

I want to close a popup when user tap over it. But the problem is that program control is not going in tap event of popup. My xaml code is

`<Popup Name="myPopup" IsOpen="False" VerticalOffset="10" HorizontalOffset="10" IsHitTestVisible="True" Tap="myPopup_Tap">`

c# code is here.

```
 private void myPopup_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        myPopup.IsOpen = false;
    }`
```

Also I tried to add a transparent rectangle over popup so that when tap event of rectangle fired popup could disable. But none of the above is working.

Please suggest me the best way to do it. Your answers appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Please set a transparent back ground for the the Popup which is to be tapped.

Comment: Finally the solution that worked is here.

`private void showPopup()
 {     
     myPopup.Child = new Image
     {
         Source = ((Image)sender).Source,
         Stretch = Stretch.Fill,
         Height = 470,
         Width = 460
      };
      myPopup.Child.Tap += Child_Tap;
      myPopup.IsOpen = true;
  }`
        
  `void Child_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
   {
         myPopup.IsOpen = false;
   }`